# Django rest_framework request post data to remote server using class views and modelviewset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and rest_frameworks. A Django app that is using REST_Framework which looks like below[image: The image shows the Django rest framework]

The goal is that when a a POST is called, the form data/json is sent to remote server url, using "request.post". Currently the code gives no errors, however the data is not posted to the remote server url.
My sample code for the class view is below:

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows containers to be viewed or edited.
"""
queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def snippet_detail(self, request):
    Snippet = self.get_object()
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
    headers= {"Content-type":"application/json", "encoding":"utf-8"}
    url = "http://198.0.10.1:5000/create?name=rstudio"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(serializer), headers =headers)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.data` to the serializer in `json.dumps`.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(serializer.data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried that adding '.data' did not  work

Comment: Does `return Response(serializer.data, ...` return the data as expected?

Comment: Yes. Also I tried hard-coding the data i.e payload =  {
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "Tty": true,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": true,
    "Image": "data52.projects.local:2544/Docker-rstudio",
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
} .  Thereafter, data = json.dumps(payload)...., and still no result.  The code in the function does not execute when the POST is called.

Comment: And when you use the json argument instead: `r = requests.post(url, json=serializer.data)`